# Views: redirect to default value URL

Tags: 7, views, redirection

When you have a contextual filter in Views and the value is not in the URL, how do you make Drupal actually redirect browser to the default value that you provide, so that the value is reflected in the address bar?

Say you have a view of a company affiliates and the path is: `company/affiliates/`. If I provide a fixed value such as `oregon`, I would like the user (= the address bar) to be redirected to `company/affiliates/oregon` upon visiting `company/affiliates/`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: the only solution that worked for me was to use the Redirect module and redirect company/affiliates to company/affiliates/oregon with 307 (temporary moved). I'm not sure 307 is safe for robots, but out of all 3xx errors seemed the safest.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, set the path to company/affiliates and the contextual filter to taxonomy ID (or whatever) and set the default value to type fixed value of Oregon. So company/affiliates goes to the Oregon page but company/affiliates/New-York goes to the New York page and company/affiliates/Massachusetts goes to the Massachusetts page while after all that the plain company/affiliates and company/affiliates/Oregon goes back to the Oregon page.

Comment: Yes, that's what I originally tried and the redirect to /oregon did not take place. I tested it again - "no go".

Comment: I tried with NIDs and it worked. Did you add the % to the path? Does it work with get taxonomy id from url? If not then it's a configuration issue.